# Spring AMQP - Sender and Receiving Messages

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am facing an issue in receiving a message from RabbitMQ.
I am sending a message like below

```
        HashMap<Object, Object> senderMap=new HashMap<>();
        senderMap.put("STATUS", "SUCCESS");
        senderMap.put("EXECUTION_START_TIME", new Date());

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Constants.ADAPTOR_OP_QUEUE,senderMap);
```

If we see in RabbitMQ, we will get a fully qualified type.

**In the current scenario, we have n number of producer for the same consumer. If i use any mapper, it leads to an exception.
How will i send a message so that it doesn't contain any type_id and i can receive the message as Message object and later i can bind it to my custom object in the receiver.**

I am receiving message like below.
Could you please let me know how to use **Jackson2MessageConverter** so that message will get directly binds to my Object/HashMap from Receiver end. Also i have removed the Type_ID now from the sender.

How Message looks in RabbitMQ

> priority: 0 delivery_mode:    2 headers:
>   **ContentTypeId**:    java.lang.Object
>   **KeyTypeId**:    java.lang.Object content_encoding:  UTF-8 content_type: application/json
>   {"Execution_start_time":1473747183636,"status":"SUCCESS"}

```
@Component
public class AdapterOutputHandler {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AdapterOutputHandler.class);

    @RabbitListener(containerFactory="adapterOPListenerContainerFactory",queues=Constants.ADAPTOR_OP_QUEUE)
    public void handleAdapterQueueMessage(HashMap<String,Object> message){

        System.out.println("Receiver:::::::::::"+message.toString());

    }

}
```

Connection

```
@Bean(name="adapterOPListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory adapterOPListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);

    }
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert Message content. Could not resolve __TypeId__ in header and no defaultType provided
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultClassMapper.toClass(DefaultClassMapper.java:139)
```

**I don't want to use __TYPE__ID from sender because they are multiple senders for the same queue and only one consumer.**

Comment: *it leads to an exception* is not enough Informations. Add the stacktrace please

Comment: Actually headers in rabbitmq contains a property called type_id_. This shouldn't be. **How to send a message in which type_id_ property is not present**

`priority: 0

delivery_mode: 2

__TypeId__: com.diff.approach.JobListenerDTO**

content_encoding: UTF-8

content_type: application/json`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it leads to an exception

What exception?

> **TypeId**: com.diff.approach.JobListenerDTO

That means you are sending a DTO, not a hash map as you describe in the question.

If you want to remove the typeId header, you can use a message post processor...

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Constants.INPUT_QUEUE, dto, m -> {
    m.getMessageProperties.getHeaders().remove("__TypeId__");
    return m;
});
```

(or `, new MessagePostProcessor() {...}` if you're not using Java 8).

**EDIT**

What version of Spring AMQP are you using? With 1.6 you don't even have to remove the `__TypeId__` header - the framework looks at the listener parameter type and tells the Jackson converter the type so it automatically converts to that (if it can). As you can see here; it works fine without removing the type id...

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class So39443850Application {

    private static final String QUEUE = "so39443850";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So39443850Application.class, args);
        context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class).convertAndSend(QUEUE, new DTO("baz", "qux"));
        context.getBean(So39443850Application.class).latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        context.getBean(RabbitAdmin.class).deleteQueue(QUEUE);
        context.close();
    }

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE, containerFactory = "adapterOPListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(HashMap<String, Object> message) {
        System.out.println(message.getClass() + ":" + message);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory adapterOPListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    public static class DTO {

        private String foo;

        private String baz;

        public DTO(String foo, String baz) {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.baz = baz;
        }

        public String getFoo() {
            return this.foo;
        }

        public void setFoo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public String getBaz() {
            return this.baz;
        }

        public void setBaz(String baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
        }

    }

}
```

Result:

```
class java.util.HashMap:{foo=baz, baz=qux}
```

This is described in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-conversion)...

> In versions prior to 1.6, the type information to convert the JSON had to be provided in message headers, or a custom ClassMapper was required. Starting with version 1.6, if there are no type information headers, the type can be inferred from the target method arguments.

You can also configure a custom `ClassMapper` to always return `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks Gary,
One more question, How to receive this message ?
`headers: 
__ContentTypeId__: java.lang.Object
__KeyTypeId__: java.lang.Object
content_encoding: UTF-8
content_type: application/json`

Comment: I am receiving the message like below

`@RabbitListener(containerFactory="adapterOPListenerContainerFactory",queues=Constants.ADAPTOR_OP_QUEUE)
 public void handleAdapterQueueMessage(Message message){
  byte[] body = message.getBody();
}`

How to convert from byte[] to hashmap back ??

Comment: Don't put code in comments - it's unreadable - edit your question instead. You need a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` in the listener container factory.

Comment: Hello Gary, I have added my receiver code, could you please suggest how to use `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`

Comment: Version of Spring AMQP - `1.6.1.RELEASE`
Version of Spring RabbitMQ - `1.5.6.RELEASE`

Comment: Why are you using mismatched versions? That won't work; they need to be the same version. If you are using maven or gradle, you only need to declare `spring-rabbit` and the corresponding version of `spring-amqp` will be pulled in automatically (transitively). Regardless, you should always use the same versions for both jars; the current version is 1.6.2.RELEASE - see [the project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/).

Comment: Yes Gary. I used the same versions for both now. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Want to use "a" different Java calss when receive message?

  Config @Bean Jackson2JsonMessageConverter with a custom [ClassMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/index.html?org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/ClassMapper.html)
- Want to use "many" different Java calss when receive message? such as :

  ```
  @MyAmqpMsgListener
  void handlerMsg(
          // Main message class, by MessageConverter
          @Payload MyMsg myMsg, 

          // Secondary message class - by MessageConverter->ConversionService
          @Payload Map<String, String> map,

          org.springframework.messaging.Message<MyMsg> msg,
          org.springframework.amqp.core.Message amqpMsg
  ) {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  Provide a custom @Bean `Converter`, `ConversionService`， `RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` :

  ```
  @Bean
  FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean rabbitMqCs(
          Set<Converter> converters
  ) {
      FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean fac = new FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean();
      fac.setConverters(converters);
      return fac;
  }
  @Bean
  DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory(
          @Qualifier("rabbitMqCs")
          FormattingConversionService rabbitMqCs
  ) {
      DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory defaultFactory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
      defaultFactory.setConversionService(rabbitMqCs);
      return defaultFactory;
  }

  // copied from RabbitBootstrapConfiguration
  @Bean(name = RabbitListenerConfigUtils.RABBIT_LISTENER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
  @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
  public RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor rabbitListenerAnnotationProcessor(
          MessageHandlerMethodFactory handlerFac
  ) {
      RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
      bpp.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(handlerFac);
      return bpp;
  }

  @Bean(name = RabbitListenerConfigUtils.RABBIT_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME)
  public RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry defaultRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry() {
      return new RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry();
  }
  ```

References:

- [Jackson2JsonMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/htmlsingle/#json-message-converter)
- [AMQP-461](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-461)
- Debugging source code [PayloadArgumentResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/PayloadArgumentResolver.java#L141)